# Change Wordpress URL in sql file via Terminal

Tags: database, migration, command-line

I've got a 40mb database file that I've exported from an old host and need to import it into a new host on a new domain. I normally open up the database in my code editor and find-replace, but as this file is so big, it's freezing my editor.

Is there a way to do this via Terminal / the command line? I saw something about using `sed` when searching, but I can't get my head around how it works. Is there a simple command for doing this that exists already? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
sed 's/http:\/\/www.domain.com/http:\/\/www.newdomain.com/g' mydatabase.sql
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Osu

Comment: Are you using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/)?

Comment: Hi Sven, no I'm not. Sounds like that could be another option though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use this technique to change the URL of your site : WordPress sometimes stores URLs in serialized strings. You find/replace will corrupt the serialized data and discard the whole content.

You can use [interconnect/it search and replace tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to change the domain without any risk. This tool even allow you to run a dry test to check what will be modified.

EDIT 2023: this search and replace tool is now integrated in [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) so it is usable in command line.

If you prefer the `sed` technique, you should escape all special characters that have special meanings in regex like dots :

```
sed 's|http://www\.domain\.com|http://www\.newdomain\.com|g' mydatabase.sql
```

Comment: Thank you Fabien, I didn't realise a simple search and replace in the database file itself could cause so many issues. Good to know!